# PCI USB Controller: Suddenly Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0

Tags: power-management, pci

I have a USB controller that gives me additional USB3 ports. It is plugged into a PCI slot. This thing worked for several years and it still works under Windows, however, suddenly, I get a

```
pcieport 0000:06:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
```

error in Ubuntu. The USB devices that I plugged in there do not work of course. Since I did not actively change anything, I assume the issue appeared after a recent update. Is there something I can do except wait for another update that fixes it?

System: Linux 5.19.0-45-generic #46~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC